# python3 inheritance self.method() vs super.method()

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance, super, self

Consider the following code example: what is the difference between using `self.method()` vs `super.method()`. If `class B` is inherited from `class A`, but has not overridden the method `p`, then doesn't `super().p()` and `self.p()` do the same thing? Which way is more correct? I assume that using `super()` will explicitly call the base class method whereas `self.p()` could run into problems if someone overrides method p.

```
class A:
    def p(self):
        print("A")

class B(A):
    def c(self):
        self.p()
    def d(self):
        super().p()

>>> b = B()
>>> b.c()
A
>>> b.d()
A
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your *current example* there is indeed no difference, both `super().p()` and `self.p()` end up calling the same method. That's because there is no *other* `p` attribute on the `B` class to be found.

Which one is more correct depends on what you want to happen when additional code introduces `p` *somewhere*. That can be on the instance, the `B` class itself (later on in the application development cycle, by you or another developer), or on a new class that inherits from `B`.

The moment you add another `p` callable attribute (a new method, say) to be found on `self`, `super().p()` and `self.p()` will produce different outcomes. And you can add such an attribute directly on the instance, or on the `B` class, or you could create a class `C` that inherits from `B` and defines that method. In all 3 cases, `self.p()` would find the new definition, while `super()` would not. Note that `self` also looks at attributes directly on the *instance itself*, while `super()` only considers class attributes on parent classes.

Demo adding an attribute on the instance; a `lambda` is just a short way of defining a function:

```
>>> b_instance = B()
>>> b_instance.p = lambda: print('p directly defined on the b instance')
>>> b_instance.c()
p directly defined on the b instance
>>> b_instance.d()
A
```

Demo with adding the method directly on the class (you can add methods as new attributes on a class after defining it):

```
>>> B.p = lambda self: print('The p method defined on B')
>>> b_instance = B()
>>> b_instance.c()
The p method defined on B
>>> b_instance.d()
A
>>> del B.p  # delete the new method again to go back to the original state
```

Demo with a new class:

```
>>> class C(B):
...     def p(self):
...         print('The p method defined on C')
...
>>> c_instance = C()
>>> c_instance.c()
The p method defined on C
>>> c_instance.d()
A
```

So the difference between `self` and `super()`, is where the search for an attribute starts. `self` starts on the *instance itself* first, then the class hierarchy starting at `type(self)`. `super()` only looks at classes that follow the *current* class (where the method is defined) in the Method Resolution Order (as recorded in the class `__mro__` attribute).

The MROs of the different classes are:

```
>>> A.__mro__
(<class '__main__.A'>, <class 'object'>)
>>> B.__mro__
(<class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class 'object'>)
>>> C.__mro__
(<class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class 'object'>)
```

so pretty straightforward, as you didn't use multiple inheritance.

For the above examples, `self.p()` looks at:

- the `__dict__` dictionary of the instance, if a `p` key exists there, the value is called. This is the first example.
- each class in `type(instance).__mro__`, so depending on the example the search would include all of `C`, `B`, `A` and then `object`.

and the `p` attribute was found at `B.p` in the second example, `C.p` in the third.

But in *all* examples above, the `super().p()` search only looks at `B.__mro__`, first locating `B`, then starting at the next class in the list, finding `A.p`.

The most common assumption is that you'd want to be able to override `p` in a subclass, so for most use-cases, you'd stick with `self.p()`.

Answer (score 0):

As you've surmised yourself, there is only a difference if your inheriting class (*B*) is overriding your function (*p*).

Depending on context you may want to force the class to always use the inherited function, but for common practice I would always refer to the own function (because if it's there in the future it's probably there for a reason).